# Adddays method for MaskedTextBox

Tags: vb.net

Following code gives first day of month of selection date.

For example if selection date of month calendar control is 20.02.2016 then following code gives 01.02.2016.

```
CLng((DateValue(MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.AddDays(-MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Day + 1).ToShortDateString).ToOADate))
```

I have decided to replace MonthCalendar1 control with MaskedTextBox1 control.

So, how to redesign above code for MaskedTextBox1 control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim _date As Date = Date.Parse(MaskedTextBox1.Text)
Dim _firstDayOfMonth As Date = New Date(_date.Year, _date.Month, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved.